# Google Chrome upload button is rendered oddly

Tags: html, upload, button, google-chrome

I put upload button to my webpage, but oddly Google Chrome renedring of upload is very odd. It has this text ("E...a") which I have never ever entered anywhere and it dosen't look at all like other browsers renedering. Are there any ways to make Chrome upload button to look like it looks in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's width is too short and it got a little... compressed :).